# Autofac - Injecting specific instance of interface

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have an ASP.NET MVC project with 2 instances of the database repository interface (`IDBSessionFactory`): one for the data database and one for the config database. In my Bootstrapper, this is how I am wiring up the DI:

```
// using ...

builder.Register(c => new DbSessionFactory("dataDB", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
    .Named<IDbSessionFactory>("datadb")
    .InstancePerHttpRequest()
    .InstancePerApiRequest();

builder.Register(c => new DbSessionFactory("configDB", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
    .Named<IDbSessionFactory>("configdb")
    .InstancePerHttpRequest()
    .InstancePerApiRequest();

builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

I have some controller classes which needs the `"configDB"` instance of `IDBSessionFactory` as an input parameter. How do I go about achieving that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to use **named** parameters while registering controllers. My strategy is to register ALL controllers against the datadb parameter and then register specific controllers against the configdb parameter. The only thing to watch is to keep the **parameter names** consistent in all the controller classes.

```
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).WithParameters(new[] { 
                        new ResolvedParameter((p, c) => p.Name == "dbSessionFactory", (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IDbSessionFactory>("datadb")) 
                    });

// Register controllers which need a specific named type            
builder.RegisterType<Web.Controllers.AdminController>().WithParameters(new[] { new ResolvedParameter((p, c) => p.Name == "sessionFactory", (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IDbSessionFactory>("configdb")) });
// Wire up the account controller with the config database instance, since all the user tables are there
builder.RegisterType<Web.Controllers.AccountController>().WithParameters(new[] { 
                        new ResolvedParameter((p, c) => p.Name == "dbSessionFactory", (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IDbSessionFactory>("configdb")) 
                        , new ResolvedParameter((p,c) => p.Name == "logger",(p,c) => c.Resolve<ILogger>())
                        , new ResolvedParameter((p,c) => p.Name == "formsAuth",(p,c) => c.Resolve<IFormsAuthentication>())
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Autofac, registrations are last-in-wins. This means that, after you call `RegisterControllers`, you can simply do one-off registrations for the controllers you want to override and they will take effect.

**Example:**

```
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.Register(c =>
    new FooController(c.ResolveNamed<IDbSessionFactory>("configDB")));

// ...

container.Resolve<FooController>()  // Resolves FooController with configDB
```

Comment: Are you sure? When I do as you suggested, Autofac throws an exception because it does not know which instance to inject, since I have registered 2 named instances in my example above.

Comment: @Shailen Sukul: Let's say you have a controller named `FooController`, which `RegisterControllers` registers for you. You can then register `FooController` by hand and reference the "configDB" or "dataDB" components via `ResolveNamed`. When resolving `FooController`, Autofac will provide your by-hand registration *instead of* the automatic one. Does that make sense?

Comment: I did use ResolveNamed along with ResolvedParameter to get it working.. the combination did the trick for me..
My point was the last in wins part did not work as expected.. I had to explicitly tie every controller with a specific instance of the IDBSessionFactory class.. 
thanks for your help